# MultiStar Schema

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, relational-database, database-schema

I have been struggling one problem for a while and still not sure if my solution is ok, please help.
I have one fact table lets say PointsTable. The table purpose is to truck how many points has every individual. My problem is that you gain points in multiple ways that I have to keep track (have a dimension table) about. So you can gain and loose points by:
buying them (**PurchaseTable**)
transferring them (**TransferTable**)
selling them (**SalesTable**)
etc.
My Solution I have a fact table (PointsTable) and i have many foreign keys columns. Structure looks like this:
**PointsTable:**
PointsTable_ID 
PointsTable_points
PointsTable_date
PointsTable_Reason (buy, transfer, sale)
PurchaseTable_ID
TransferTable_ID
SalesTable_ID

And depending on each reason the ID column is filled with proper data but the rest ID fields are left blank. 
Is there another way of solving this issue, with no blank fields?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Its difficult to make an assessment of a model with very little information.

Is it not possible to build a single dimension table by combining tables: Purchase, Transfer & Sales?
This dimension table may have a field in it indicating 'P, F or S'.

Your Fact table then houses a single foreign key (no blank fields) to this dimension table?

Comment: Thank you for your comment,
Not really each demension Table has specific fields so TransferTable has details about transfer, PurchaseTable has specific fields about purchase like (price, unit, tax) etc. The combining table is in fact the fact table

Answer (score 0):

You cannot leave a foreign key blank. Enter 0 or -1 in fact table for every ID you wanted to leave blank. Each dimension has a row keyed to 0 or -1 to denote no transaction occurred.